# How to check if there is any data in content provider

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-contentprovider

Hi I am new to Android Development. Im working with Android Kotlin. I want to check whether there is any data in the content provider. This is the sample code that I tried in mainactivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        val AUTHORITY = "com.wsample.moblity.auth"
        val CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://$AUTHORITY")
    }
    var c:Cursor? = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (c!!.count != 0) {
            Log.d("COUNT", "NOT ZERO")
        } else {
            Log.d("COUNT 1", "ZERO")
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}
```

But I'm geting an exception like,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

move this line into onCreate function

var c:Cursor? = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)

Comment: I did that,but now I got error like: Failed to find provider info for com.wsample.moblity.auth. Is it necessary to specify the path upto the table name?